# Accidentally sent USDT to USDT contract address instead of wallet

Tags: usdt

This was actually on the tron network but I need a reply ASAP
I accidentally pasted the tron USDT contract address instead of my wallet address when receiving money.
Is there any way the money will bounce back or is it gone forever?

https://tronscan.org/#/token20/TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t/code

I know tron is different than ethereum network but any guesses if my money is gone forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry whether on Tron or Ethereum it's the same you send your crypto to USDT contract and as no private key is attached to a smart contract it will not be possible for you to recover your funds (unless you make a chain fork).

Comment: thank you, i thought so but wanted to be sure

Comment: This is not accurate (even though the conclusion is correct): if the USDT contract was implementing a way to transfer token out of its address, it could be done - "contract private key" is not relevant.